# is there any eclipse plugin available for writing a memo on any line of code?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Doe anybody know of an eclipse plugin, which can be used to insert short text (in the form of memo) to remember what that line of code does or a block of code does to help me understand the existing code better and i can also refer it back later on.

Just like "Task" can be added on a line of code, although i can use "tasks" for this purpose, but that is not very convenient and intuitive.

Comment: Not trying to be rude, but imho this should be handled by javadoc (or something similar if not using Java) and external documentation. If you feel there is a need to comment the code, then you probably need to refactor it to smaller methods/classes to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a short text to "remember what that line of code does or a block of code does to help me understand the existing code better", use comments. That's what they're for, and practically every formal language in the world has them.

If you want the ability to quickly jump to an arbitrary point in the code, using bookmarks is a convenient option - right click the bar immediately left of the text and choose to add a bookmark. You can then easily jump between bookmarks with the "bookmark view", which you can enable from the Window -> Show View menu.

Comment: Well, agreed that comments in the code is used for just that, but thinking from a perspective of a totally stranger person to a project and if he wants to understand the code leaving the trail of useful text behind, so that he can refer them back, if needed, and this text may not be useful or constructive for a person already working on the code or at worst could not be used as a javadoc comment.

Comment: @Sudhir I have to admit that's a fair point. I usually use bookmarks for that, in combination with an external document.

Comment: You cannot add bookmarks to external JAR files. Major bummer.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of is bookmark support.  There is native bookmark support in Eclipse and also several other vendors supply more function.

I'm assuming that there's a very good reason that you don't want to or can't modify the code.